# Why firebase takes more time to store and fetch data?

Tags: android, sqlite, firebase-realtime-database

I built a chat app in which I use firebase realtime database and sqlite database also.
Within chat activity whenever user send the message it store to the firebase as well as sqlite also.

The things are happen:

1. when activity start, few send messages of starting store instantly in firebase , but after the addition of more messagges in firebase its take time like 3sec, 5sec, 15sec, 30sec, 1min, 3min
2. I think firebase will tired or confused after store more and more nodes.

Send message code

```
 private void addMessageInSqlite()
    {
        String messageText=userMessageInput.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(messageText))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "please write message first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            String message_sender_ref="Messages/"+MessageSenderId+"/"+MessageReceiverId;
            String message_receiver_ref="Messages/"+MessageReceiverId+"/"+MessageSenderId;

            DatabaseReference user_msg_key=rootRef.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageReceiverId).push();
            String message_push_id=user_msg_key.getKey();
            Long tsLong = System.currentTimeMillis();
            SQLiteDatabase db= myDbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
            SQLiteDatabase tempMessageDb= unsendMessageDbHendler.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(COLUMN_MESSAGE, messageText);
            values.put(COLUMN_FROM, MessageSenderId);
            values.put(COLUMN_TYPE, "text");
            values.put(COLUMN_TIMESTAMP,tsLong);
            values.put(COLUMN_PUSH_KEY,message_push_id);
            values.put(COLUMN_DELIVERY,0);
            values.put(COLUMN_SEEN,0);
            long rowInserted = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null, values);
            if(rowInserted != -1)
            {
                Log.v("sqlitesave","ok");
                ConnectivityManager cm=(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                if(netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "internet active", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Map messageTextBodyForSender=new HashMap();
                    messageTextBodyForSender.put("message",messageText);
                    messageTextBodyForSender.put("type","text");
                    messageTextBodyForSender.put("from",MessageSenderId);
                    messageTextBodyForSender.put("timestamp",tsLong);
                    messageTextBodyForSender.put("seen",false);
                    messageTextBodyForSender.put("delivery",false);

                    Map messageBodyDetail=new HashMap();
                    messageBodyDetail.put(message_sender_ref+"/"+message_push_id,messageTextBodyForSender);
                    rootRef.updateChildren(messageBodyDetail).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task)
                        {
                            if(task.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(MessageActivity.this, "message sent successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                MediaPlayer IncomingMessageSound=MediaPlayer.create(MessageActivity.this,R.raw.incoming_message_sound);
                                IncomingMessageSound.start();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                String error=task.getException().toString();
                                Toast.makeText(MessageActivity.this, ""+error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MessageActivity.this, "internet not active", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    tempMessageDb.insert(SENDER_TEMP_MESSAGE,null, values);
                    ContentValues valuesforreceiver = new ContentValues();
                    valuesforreceiver.put(COLUMN_MESSAGE, messageText);
                    valuesforreceiver.put(COLUMN_FROM, MessageSenderId);
                    valuesforreceiver.put(COLUMN_TYPE, "text");
                    valuesforreceiver.put(COLUMN_TIMESTAMP,tsLong);
                    valuesforreceiver.put(COLUMN_PUSH_KEY,message_push_id);
                    tempMessageDb.insert(RECEIVER_TEMP_MESSAGE,null, valuesforreceiver);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Log.v("sqlitesave","nok");
            }
            db.close();
            tempMessageDb.close();
            refreshLayout();
            Map messageTextBodyForReceiver=new HashMap();
            messageTextBodyForReceiver.put("message",messageText);
            messageTextBodyForReceiver.put("type","text");
            messageTextBodyForReceiver.put("from",MessageSenderId);
            messageTextBodyForReceiver.put("timestamp",tsLong);

            Map messageBodyDetail=new HashMap();
            messageBodyDetail.put(message_receiver_ref+"/"+message_push_id,messageTextBodyForReceiver);
            rootRef.updateChildren(messageBodyDetail).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task)
                {
                    if(task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(MessageActivity.this, "message sent successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        MediaPlayer IncomingMessageSound=MediaPlayer.create(MessageActivity.this,R.raw.incoming_message_sound);
                        IncomingMessageSound.start();
                        userMessageInput.setText("");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        String error=task.getException().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(MessageActivity.this, ""+error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        userMessageInput.setText("");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

And fetching messages from firebase code is:

```
rootRef.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageReceiverId).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s)
            {
                refreshLayout();
                Messages messages=dataSnapshot.getValue(Messages.class);
                String pushKey=dataSnapshot.getKey();
                String selectQuery= "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME +  " WHERE pushkey  = '"+pushKey+"'";
                if(myDbHandler.getData(selectQuery).getCount()>0)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    myDbHandler.retrieveMessgaefromReceiver(messages,pushKey);
                    refreshLayout();

                }
            }
```

Comment: use setValue instead of updatechildren it might be helpful

Comment: I also used but it still takes a time thanks

Comment: If you think the Firebase writes are getting slower, reproduce that exact problem in a minimum piece of code that others can run too. Typically this means you should include no UI, using logging to show progress/timing, and have no dependencies on other code.

Comment: For this what should i do ?